# xpath for an webelement which is having two inner text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am using selenium-java with version 4.1.4. I am trying to read a text from the UI.The HTML code is given below.

```
<div class="css-1o5t8tj">
     <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-caption css-wev09c">
         "$"
         "10.99"
     </span>
     <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-caption css-1kcldpk">
         "$"
         "13.44"
     </span>
 </div>
```

I have used below code to read the text

```
 String txt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='css-1o5t8tj']//span[1]")).getText() ;
```

But it returns empty string.Actually here i am expecting the String txt = "$10.99". Is there any way to get this text? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The XPath is okay. Something else is wrong.  Ate those `css-1o5t8tj` strings maybe random?

Comment: You have extra parenthesis in the end. String txt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='css-1o5t8tj']//span[1]")).getText();. For me code is worked.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed, The class css-1o5t8t is not random.

Comment: @K.Nikita, the extra parenthesis in the end, is a typing error happened from my side. I have edited that in the question.

Comment: @Devleena please show me all code. I think error in another place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath -

```
(//div/span[contains(@class='MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-caption')])[1]
```